# Difference between two independent binomial random variables with equal success probability

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> Let $X$ ~ $Bin(n,p)$ and $Y$ ~ $Bin(m,p)$ be two independent random variables. Find the distribution of $Z=X-Y$.

see also [Difference of two binomial random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562119/difference-of-two-binomial-random-variables)

I figured this out:

$$ P(Z=z)=\cases{\sum_{i=o}^{min(m,n)} Bin(k+i,n,p)*Bin(i,m,p), &if $z\ge0$;\cr \sum_{i=0}^{min(m,n)} Bin(i,n,p) * Bin(i-z, m, p),&otherwise. \cr}$$

I also validated it by Monte Carlo simulation. For $n=30$, $m=20$ and $p=0.5$, I get the following distribution, where the circles are the analytical probabilities and the line connects the MC estimates.

[image]

Because that looked to me pretty much like a binomial distribution, I gave it a try and figured out that its actually a binomial, just shifted by m to the left. This can be simply written as $P(Y=y) = Bin(y+m, m+n, p)$. Hence, given equal success probabilities, the sum of two independent binomially distributed random variables is binomial, but also their difference, just shifted to the left.

This question here [difference between independent binomial variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957206/difference-between-independent-binomial-variables) is actually the same as mine, but received no answer and only the comment that there would be no simple formula. But the above formula looks pretty simple to me.

- Is it correct that for the case of equal success probabilities, the above equations actually describes the distribution of $Z=X-Y$?
- I read in a book that $Z$ could not be binomial distributed because it had negative support. Is it right to call it a shifted binomial?

Comment: Are you sure that your derivation is correct? Even for the simplest case of $X$ and $Y$ being independent binomials random variables with parameters $(1,p)$, $$P\{X-Y = 1\} = P\{X-Y = -1\} = p(1-p),\quad P\{X-Y=0\} = p^2+(1-p)^2$$ which is _not_ a shifted binomial distribution except when $p=\frac 12$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your $Z=X-Y$ will not be a "shifted binomial" unless $p=\frac12$, or the trivial cases where at least one of $n$ and $m$ is zero.  For the case $p=\frac12$, $m-Y$ has the same distribution as $Y$ so $X+Y$ and $X-Y+m$ have the same distribution, which is indeed binomial.

In general consider the means and variances of the distributions:

- $X$ has mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$
- $Y$ has mean $mp$ and variance $mp(1-p)$
- $X+Y$ has mean $(n+m)p$ and variance $(n+m)p(1-p)$
- $Z=X-Y$ has mean $(n-m)p$ and variance $(n+m)p(1-p)$
- $Z+m=X-Y+m$ has mean $np+m(1-p)$ and variance $(n+m)p(1-p)$

So for $Z+m$ to be binomial and to be supported on the integers from $0$ through to $n+m$, if its parameter was $q$, its mean would be $(n+m)q$ and variance $(n+m)q(1-q)$.

- To have $(n+m)q(1-q)=(n+m)p(1-p)$ requires $q=p$ or $q=1-p$ or $n+m=0$ (i.e. $n=m=0$).
- To have $q=p$ or $q=1-p$ and the two expressions for the mean equal requires $(n+m)p=np+m(1-p)$ or $(n+m)(1-p)=np+m(1-p)$, i.e. $mp=m(1-p)$ or $n(1-p)=np$, which would require $p=\frac12$ or $m=0$ or $n=0$.

So the only case where $n\gt0$ and $m\gt0$ where the means and variances match a binomial distribution is when $p=\frac12$.

Answer (score 4):

If $n$ and $m$ are sufficiently large, you can use the [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation):

> $X \approx N[np,npq]$
>
> $Y \approx N[mp,mpq]$
>
> $X-Y \approx N[mp-np,mpq+npq]$

Comment: For completeness, I would also add a link to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html