# Difference of two binomial random variables with identical distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution

Is there a closed form answer for absolute value of difference of two identical binomial random variables with identical distributions when $p=1/2$?
In particular, what is the the distribution of $|X-Y|$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent and both $~Bin(n,1/2)$?

Comment: Relevant (general case): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562119/difference-of-two-binomial-random-variables

Comment: I guess that is not a closed form answer as it uses the hypergeomteric function.

Comment: No, but it is still relevant for future searches, and having a link here helps in that. (Another one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065487/difference-between-two-independent-binomial-random-variables-with-equal-success)

Comment: Note that what you want can be rephrased as follows: what is the probability distribution of $\lvert X - n\rvert$, where $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(2n,\frac{1}{2})$? (I.e., the distribution of the "distance from the mean")

Comment: You need to assume your two binomial random variables are independent.

Comment: Thank Clement. Can you explain how these two are equivalent?

Comment: Yes they are also independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the various answers at the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562119/difference-of-two-binomial-random-variables), it looks as if 
$$P(|X-Y|=0)={2n \choose n} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$ 
while for positive $z$ $$P(|X-Y|=z)={2n \choose n+z} \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$$

Comment: And now I read the second linked question where [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1065670/6460) said in passing "For the case $p=\frac12$, $m-Y$ has the same distribution as $Y$ so $X+Y$ and $X-Y+m$ have the same distribution, which is indeed binomial." $m$ there is $n$ here