# What is the distribution of the difference of two normalized binomial random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X \sim Bin(n, p)$ and $Y \sim Bin(m, p)$.

How is

$$Z_1 = \frac{X}{n} - \frac{Y}{m}$$

and

$$Z_2 = \left|\frac{X}{n} - \frac{Y}{m}\right|$$

distributed? (Hence: What is their cumulative distribution function?)

### Background

I am mainly interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557711/6876) and answering the question here will help me for the other one (I hope).

### My thoughts

The range of values of $Z_1$ is $(-1, 1)$ and of $Z_2$ is $(0, 2)$. Both are discrete random variables.

\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E} (Z_1) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{n} - \frac{Y}{m}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E}(X) - \frac{1}{m} \mathbb{E}(Y) \\
&= p - p \\
&= 0\\
F_X(x) & =\operatorname P(X\le x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\binom nk p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\
F_{X/n}(x) &= P\left(\frac{X}{n} \leq x\right)\\
           &= P(X \leq nx)\\
           &= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor nx \rfloor}\binom nk p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\
F_{Z_1}(x) &= P\left(\frac{X}{n} - \frac{Y}{m} \leq x\right)\\
           &= ?\\
\end{align}

Is there probably some continuous approximation of those discrete distributions?

Comment: Did you consider an approximation via normal distribution?  In this case $X/n\approx N(p,p(1-p)/n)$.  In case of independence $Z_1\approx N(0,p(1-p)/n+p(1-p)/m)$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe No, not so far. But with n and m >= 50 it should be applicable, right?

Comment: @MartinThoma As long as the variances are more then $9$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation

Comment: As $var(X) = n \cdot p \cdot (1-p)$, for $n=50$ I would need p in about $[0.235, 0.765]$. For $n=100$ I would need $p$ to be in $[0.10, 0.90]$. Right?