# Expected absolute difference of binomials

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Suppose that $X \sim \textrm{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y \sim \textrm{Bin}(n,p)$ are independent and identically distributed variables.

Is there a nice way to calculate the expectation of their absolute difference, i.e., $\mathbb{E}\left|X - Y\right|$? or even a good upper bound on it?

From some searching, (e.g., [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562119/difference-of-two-binomial-random-variables)) it looks like the overall distribution has no simple form but I'm wondering if it might be easier to find the expected value.

Another potentially relevant work I found is [https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~karyeh/sharp-mad.pdf](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Ekaryeh/sharp-mad.pdf), which calculates bound on a closely related value $\mathbb{E}\left|X - \mathbb{E}(X)\right|$. For $p$ which is not too close the endpoints, $\mathbb{E}\left|X - \mathbb{E}(X)\right|$ is bounded by the s.d. of $X$.

I'm wondering if some similar $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ bound would also work for $\mathbb{E}\left|X - Y\right|$.

A generalization where $X \sim \textrm{Bin}(n_1,p_1)$ and $Y \sim \textrm{Bin}(n_2,p_2)$ are still independent would also be useful.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality should give desired sqrt(n) bound.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: from  E(|X-Y|) \leq sqrt{ E((X-Y)^2) }  you can expand the right hand side using the fact X and Y are independent

Comment: Yup, looks like this works. Thanks!